# Ensure that all elements in a structure are initialized

Tags: c, gcc

I a C source code, I would like to ensure that all elements of my structure are well initilized. It would be easy with the warning Wmissing-field-initializers. But I also would like to be able to initialize my elements using designated initilizer.

for example:

```
struct s {
  int a;
  int b;
};

struct s s1 = { .a = 1, .b = 2 };
struct s s2 = { .a = 1 };
struct s s3 = { 1, 2 };
struct s s4 = { 1 };
```

Let's try to compile this:

```
$ gcc -Wmissing-field-initializers -c struct_init.c 
struct_init.c:9:8: warning: missing initializer
struct_init.c:9:8: warning: (near initialization for ‘s4.b’)
```

I would like the compilation fails for s2 initilization too. I do prefer designated initiazation, as it facilitates source code reading.

Comment: Time to fire up the clang API documentation.

Comment: But in the second case n *is* well initialized, to 0.

Comment: cnicutar, with a classical initialization, .b will also be well initialized to zero, but gcc will raise a warning.

Answer (score 4):

When you use designation initializers, the missing members are initialized to `0`. This is the case even if the object has automatic storage duration. To my knowledge there is no `gcc` option that can warn about the members that are *not* explicitly initialized when you use  designation initializers.

Comment: Not sure about your first statement. In my knowledge if -O2 or higher optimization flag is used, initialization do not occur.

Comment: @ManojR a compiler that would not initialize the missing members, even  at `-O2`, is not a C compiler. The initialization is guaranteed by the C Standard, see 6.7.8p21 in C99.

Answer (score 2):

You could use -Werror to turn warnings into errors or alternatively -Werror=missing-field-initializers to only turn the field initializer warning into an error.

More info here: [GCC Warning Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Edit:
I just ran a test using [splint](http://www.splint.org/) with no additional options which gave the following output:

```
main.c:13:17: Initializer block for s2 has 1 field, but struct s has 2 fields:
             <error>
  Initializer does not set every field in the structure. (Use -fullinitblock to
  inhibit warning)
main.c:15:17: Initializer block for s4 has 1 field, but struct s has 2 fields:
             1
```

It may not be exactly what you are after since you need to run this manually against your source but it will warn about missing designated initializers.

Comment: I already specified that this warning doesn't work with dsignated initialization.

Comment: From [the GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wmissing-field-initializers-521): "This option does not warn about designated initializers"