# How to ensure structures are completly initialized (by name) in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc

How do I ensure each and every field of my structures are initialized in GCC when using designated initializers? (I'm especially interested in function pointers.) (I'm  using C not C++.)

Here is an example:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} foo_t;

typedef struct {
    void (*Start)(void);
    void (*Stop)(void);
} bar_t;

foo_t fooo = { 
        5 
    };

foo_t food = { 
        .b=4 
    };

bar_t baro = {
        NULL
    };

bar_t bard = { 
        .Start = NULL
    };
```

-Wmissing-field-initializers does not help at all. It works for fooo only in **GCC** (mingw 4.7.3, 4.8.1), and **clang** does only marginally better (no warnings for food and bard).

I'm sure there is a reason for not producing warnings for designated initializer (even when I explicitly ask for them) but I want/need them. I do not want to initialize structures based on order/position because that is more error prone (for example swapping Start and Stop won't even give any warning). And neither gcc nor clang will give any warning that I failed to explicitly initialize a field (when initializing by name). I also don't want to litter my code with if(x.y==NULL) lines for multiple reasons, one of which is I want compile time warnings and not runtime errors.

At least **splint** will give me warnings on all 4 cases, but unfortunately I cannot use splint all the time (it chokes on some of the code (fails to parse some C99, GCC extensions)).

Note: If I'm using a real function instead of NULL GCC will also show a warning for baro (but not bard).

I searched google and stack overflow but only found related questions and have not found answer for this specific problem.
The best match I have found is 'Ensure that all elements in a structure are initialized'
[Ensure that all elements in a structure are initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122983/ensure-that-all-elements-in-a-structure-are-initialized)
Which asks pretty much the same question, but has no satisfying answer.

Is there a better way dealing with this that I have not mentioned? 
(Maybe other code analysis tool? Preferably something (free) that can be integrated into Eclipse or Visual Studio...)

Comment: There is an answer at the question you linked that suggests splint.

Answer (score 6):

If I'm not mistaken, the C standards *specify* that the other fields are **automatically initialized with 0**.

So what you are asking for - a compilation error when fields are not initialized - would be *out of line* with the C (modern?) specifications.

C99 standard, page 127 in: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

`gcc`s `-Wmissing-field-initializers` is documented to *not* warn with designated initializers. There is a request for an enhancement `-Wmissing-field-initializers=2` that would then warn also: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39589

So I suggest you add your wish to that bug report, or maybe even provide a patch. From my experience with open-source software, adding a patch is best.

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely correct but I intentionally used the phrase "explicitly initialize". I also told that I do not want to check for NULL function pointers in run time, because I know that the missed fields are initialized to 0. (The same explanation was also given in the referenced questin I beleive.) The fact it is legal C99 does not mean it cannot give warnings which I am requesting for.

Comment: There must be a reason why it is explicitly not included in `-Wmissing-field-initializers`, judging from the gcc documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The four ways you have showed all initialize the rest of the structure. It's initialized to 0 (or the type equivalent).